# Company ownership data

Tags: data-request

I am trying to find company ownership data (e.g. names of shareholders that own say up to top x% of the shares?) for companies in any major country.

Ideally this would be associated to main industry of operation of the actual company etc.

My intention would be to do some shareholder network analysis on this basis.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had anyluck with this?

I am looking to find same sort of data set but the only thing I was able to find was SEC Edgar tool.

Use this to find to find CIK, unique for every company filed with SEC and maybe IRS
http://www.portal.edgarfiling.sec.gov/Welcome/EDGARPortal.htm

Use this to find data find company and individual filings with SEC.
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Lastly, Market Structure is provided by SEC as well, but I have not played with it.
https://www.sec.gov/marketstructure/

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the PSC (Persons with Significant Control) register of the UK's Companies House:
http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_pscdata.html

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [OpenOwnership.org](https://OpenOwnership.org), it aggregates a number of countries together, UK, SK and UA and DK.

Example data items:

- https://register.openownership.org/entities/5f46bef07bbb420af2bba3c0 You can see that TONERS & CARTRIDGES LIMITED is owned mostly by Aubrey Thomas Brocklebank.
- https://register.openownership.org/entities/59b92ae667e4ebf340156d19
  You can see how MANCHESTER UNITED LIMITED is owned by 6 levels of parent companies, with the top one being in the Cayman Islands with no disclosed ownership.

The data can be searched using this web tool: https://register.openownership.org

You can also download the whole data as compressed JSON: https://register.openownership.org/download

[Open Data Commons Attribution License](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1-0/)